# How is it that I am able to reference private fields of an instance inside a class?

Tags: java, private

I have had a look for an explanation but haven't been able to find one. Why does this code work? Specifically - why can the private members of an instance be accessed? As far as I know it only works when the instance is created in a method inside the original class.

```
public class MyClass {
    private int thing;

    public MyClass () {}

    public MyClass makeMe () {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.thing = 1;
        return myClass;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it *shouldn't* work? After all, this is in an instance method of that class.

Comment: *As far as I know it only works when the instance is created in a method inside the original class* 
So isn't that exactly what you are doing?

Comment: Doesn't matter where the instance was created. Instances don't keep track of that. It is all about where the line of code is that tries to access your `thing` (and here that is in a method inside the original class, so it's all good).

Comment: Thanks for your patience guys. Guess I was confused about private access. @Thilo - great explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A private field can only be accessed by that class.  You're still operating inside an instance of `MyClass`, so the private field is visible and accessible to you without the use of a setter.

To be a bit more formal... [JLS 6.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1) talks about access.

Here's the abridged snippet, emphasis mine:

> - A member (class, interface, field, or method) of a reference (class, interface, or array) type or a constructor of a class type is accessible only if the type is accessible and the member or constructor is declared to permit access:
>
>   - ...Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared private, then **access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class** (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

Comment: Thanks Makoto - I appreciate that I could eventually have found that by RTFM. Much obliged :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public MyClass makeMe () {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.thing = 1;
    return myClass;
}
```

is *inside* of the `MyClass` class, so it's able to access private members.